# Table TD wrap (mis)behaviour?

Tags: html, css

I have extracted my table to this simple format to narrow down the problem.

The two tables have same style defined, yet they appear differently (first one doesn't fit to the page width).
I couldn't find what's causing that, appreciate any help i can get here to make the table fit to page width.

P.S. I am not sure just pasting html code below can show you the problem I wanted to show here, so have added [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Manjz/pen/RwRBgmj) and also attached a screenshot image of the problem - hoping at least one shows-up.

[image: Screenshot Image of how I see the table in my browser]

```css
table.diff {
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #83728d;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="diff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>banner value You are cccccccccc to the MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU NNN. Use of MMMMMM BBBBBBBBBB's TT ffffffffff is governed by the IIIIIIIIIII DDDDDDDDDD AAAAAAAAAA Use Policy detailed at: https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/pppppp-bbbb/pppppppp-and-pppppppppp/mmmmmmmmmm/iii</td>

      <td>banner value You are cccccccccc to the MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU NNN. Use of MMMMMM BBBBBBBBBB's TT ffffffffff is governed by the IIIIIIIIIII DDDDDDDDDD AAAAAAAAAA Use Policy detailed at: https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/pppppp-bbbb/pppppppp-and-pppppppppp/mmmmmmmmmm/iii</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br><br>
<table class="diff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaaa vvvvv YYY aaa cccccccccc tt ttt MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU VVV. UUU oo MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU'U II ffffffffff ii gggggggg bb ttt IIIIIIIIIII TTTTTTTTTT AAAAAAAAAA UUU PPPPPP dddddddd aa: hhhhh://hhh.hhhhhh.hhh/hhhhhh-hhhh/hhhhhhhh-hhh-hhhhhhhhhh/hhhhhhhhhh/hhh</td>

      <td>aaaaaa vvvvv YYY aaa cccccccccc tt ttt MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU VVV. UUU oo MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU'U II ffffffffff ii gggggggg bb ttt IIIIIIIIIII TTTTTTTTTT AAAAAAAAAA UUU PPPPPP dddddddd aa: hhhhh://hhh.hhhhhh.hhh/hhhhhh-hhhh/hhhhhhhh-hhh-hhhhhhhhhh/hhhhhhhhhh/hhh</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the weirdest thing. It even persists if we swap the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a simple one, you don't have real spaces, you only have one big word.

```
banner&nbsp;value&nbsp;You&nbsp;....... VS banner value. You
```

Add this to your table.diff and it will fix your problem.

```
word-break: break-all;
```

or even better looking:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

The above can happen if you copy paste your text from a word editor or you do some other kind of formatting.

Comment: break-all did work for me, thanks for that :-) , unfortunately it broke few other things in my original big html table. I will try to see if i can fix it, might need your help again i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is physical a way to fix your `&nbsp;` issue

```js
$("#table1 tr td").each(function() {
  this.textContent = decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(this.textContent).replace(/%C2%A0/g," "))
})
```

```css
table.diff {
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #83728d;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="diff" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>banner value You are cccccccccc to the MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU NNN. Use of MMMMMM BBBBBBBBBB's TT ffffffffff is governed by the IIIIIIIIIII DDDDDDDDDD AAAAAAAAAA Use Policy detailed at: https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/pppppp-bbbb/pppppppp-and-pppppppppp/mmmmmmmmmm/iii</td>

      <td>banner value You are cccccccccc to the MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU NNN. Use of MMMMMM BBBBBBBBBB's TT ffffffffff is governed by the IIIIIIIIIII DDDDDDDDDD AAAAAAAAAA Use Policy detailed at: https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/pppppp-bbbb/pppppppp-and-pppppppppp/mmmmmmmmmm/iii</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br><br>
<table class="diff" id="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaaa vvvvv YYY aaa cccccccccc tt ttt MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU VVV. UUU oo MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU'U II ffffffffff ii gggggggg bb ttt IIIIIIIIIII TTTTTTTTTT AAAAAAAAAA UUU PPPPPP dddddddd aa: hhhhh://hhh.hhhhhh.hhh/hhhhhh-hhhh/hhhhhhhh-hhh-hhhhhhhhhh/hhhhhhhhhh/hhh</td>

      <td>aaaaaa vvvvv YYY aaa cccccccccc tt ttt MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU VVV. UUU oo MMMMMM UUUUUUUUUU'U II ffffffffff ii gggggggg bb ttt IIIIIIIIIII TTTTTTTTTT AAAAAAAAAA UUU PPPPPP dddddddd aa: hhhhh://hhh.hhhhhh.hhh/hhhhhh-hhhh/hhhhhhhh-hhh-hhhhhhhhhh/hhhhhhhhhh/hhh</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this td style

```
word-break: break-word;
```